# checking the input type in C

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion

I want to check if my input is an integer (and not a char or string for example).
I stumbled across this code (that works):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    float a;
    int q;

    printf("\nInsert number\t");
    scanf("%f",&a);

    q=(int)a;
    ++q;

    if((q - a) != 1)
        printf("\nThe number is not an integer\n\n");
    else
        printf("\nThe number is an integer\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain why it works?

Comment: That code is unlikely to work if you enter 987654321 as the value.  It's even less likely to work if you type ABC.

Comment: This code has nothing to do with whether input is "a `char` or `string`".

Comment: *Always* test the return value from `scanf`, here it should be `1`. If you want to input an `int` then do so, check that 1 value was converted, and check that the next `char` from the input stream is whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

> I stumbled across this code (that works): ... why it works?

It does not work, in general.  Too many failing cases

Given input might be a single character `Z`, the follow code is *undefined behavior* (UB) as `scanf()` does not assign `a`.  Result: `(int)a` is UB.

```
scanf("%f",&a);
q=(int)a;
```

Given input might be "12345678901234567890", something outside the range of an `int`, then converting with `(int)a` is also UB.

If `a` takes on the value of `INT_MAX`, `++q;` is UB.

Values where the input can be exactly represented as an `int`, but not as a `float` fail OP's code.

Input that is rounded to a whole number like `"0.99999999999999999999999999999"` --> `1.0f` fail OP's detection

---

Alternative.

`scanf(), fgets()` do not read *C strings*, `int`, `float`, etc.  Instead, better to think of them as reading *text* and converting them into *C strings*, `int`, `float`.

The `f` in `scanf()` implies *formatted* input and that is the unknown part here.  Better to avoid `scanf()`.

Since code needs to detect various things about user input, use `fgets()` to read a *line* of text.  Then use `strtol()`, `strtoll()`, `strtoul()`, etc. to see if input fits into the target type.

```
// Check if input fits in a `long`
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
  puts("End-of-file or input error");
} else {
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  long ivalue = strtol(buf, &endptr, 0);
  if (buf == endptr) puts("Fail: no conversion");
  else if (*endptr != '\n' && *endptr != '\0') puts("Fail: Extra junk");
  else if (errno) puts("Fail: Overlfow");
  else printf("Success: %ld\n", ivalue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code itself is pretty simple, we are changing casting `float` to `int` and then incremented the `int` value:

```
q=(int)a;
++q;
```

Then, everytime there was an `int` provided as the input, the result of `(q-a)` will be exactly `1`. However, it the input provided (and saved to `float a`) was of type `float`, result will be greater less than `1` (for positive numbers).

This is because in `(q-a)`, `q` will be converted to `float` and the result of it will also be `float`.

Refer for example for [the C book](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter2/expressions_and_arithmetic.html):

> Otherwise, if either operand is a float, then the other one is
>   converted to float, and that is the type of the result.

Comment: [If the value being converted is outside the range of values that can be represented, the behavior is undefined.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.4p2) It is possible for `float`s to hold values not representable by `int`s.

Comment: I do not recommend using this code anywhere, the question was how it works, just explained it.

Comment: Agree about non-recommendation. Just thought that UB is an important feature of this code (also, UB if user inputs, e.g., a string), hence the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You take input `a` this is a float number. Then you are casting `float` to `int` by an integer `q` and increment `1 (q++)`. So, if you take input `a = 3.4`

`q=(int)a;
    ++q;`

then `q` will be `4`. But it can not change the value of `a`. So `a` will be `3.4`.
 After checking this condition `(q - a) != 1`  will true, otherwise false.

Finally if you take input `a=3.0` then this code will not work.(as `a=3.0` is a float number.)

Answer (score 1):

this statement:

```
scanf("%f",&a);
```

can tell you what you want to know.

When calling any of the scanf() family of functions: Always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

In this case suggest:

```
if( 1 != scanf("%f",&a) ) 
{ // non digit entered 
    ....
}
```